# How to route after calling commit()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am struggling a little with what to do after I call commit(). I want to determine how to route the user, depending on `commit()` being successful or if the server returns an error.

I read somewhere that if there is an error on the server then it can return a status code of >400 and errors as follows:

```
{ 'errors' : [ { 'errorCode' : [ 'duplicate-user' ] } ] }
```

On the client-side I have the following:

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    createUser : function () {
        'use strict';

        var user = App.User.createRecord({
                firstName : $("#firstName").val(),
                lastName : $("#lastName").val(),
                primaryEmailAddress : $("#primaryEmailAddress").val(),
                password : $("#password").val()
            }),

            commitObserver = Ember.Object.extend({
                removeObservers : function (sender) {
                    sender.removeObserver('isError', this, 'error');
                    sender.removeObserver('isValid', this, 'success');
                },
                error : function (sender, key, value) {
                    this.removeObservers(sender);
                    App.Router.router.transitionTo('duplicateuser');
                },
                success : function (sender, key, value) {
                    this.removeObservers(sender);
                    App.Router.router.transitionTo('usercreated');
                }
            });

        user.get('transaction').commit();

        user.addObserver('isError', commitObserver.create(), 'error');
        user.addObserver('isValid', commitObserver.create(), 'success');
    }
});
```

(Note: I am not using 'Ember.TextField' in my HTML hence the use of jQuery)

I have a few questions:

1. Is this the correct/best approach for handling commit()?
2. I've found I have to remove both observers as `isValid` is called after `isError` - is this to be expected?
3. How/can I access the server response as I want to be able to make a routing decision based on the error code?
4. The only way I can reference the router is through `App.Router.router` - is there a cleaner way?
5. If there is an error, do I need to do anything to remove the record from the store so it doesn't re-committed in the future?

Answer (score 1):

From within a controller, you can do this:

```
this.get('target').transitionTo('another.route')
```

or, you can send an event to the current route and transition from there:

```
this.get('target').send('eventName');
```

or if you need to pass a model:

```
this.get('target').send('eventName', this.get('content'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use controller.transitionToRoute("your.route");
See [this link](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/ext/controller.js#L8) for the source code...